# How to make editable column when row is selected in vaadin-grid using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, polymer-2.x

I want to make editable column when row is selected in vaadin-grid using **JavaScript**.

The second approach that I used is I put a **paper-input** inside of **vaadin-grid** but the value that I'm getting is **undefined**

```
<vaadin-grid items=[[loadItems]] active-item="{{activeItem}}" id="datagrid">
    <vaadin-grid-column resizable>
        <template class="header">
            <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Name">Name</vaadin-grid-sorter>
        </template>
        <template>
            [[item.Name]]
        </template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>

    <vaadin-grid-column resizable>
        <template class="header">
            <vaadin-grid-sorter path="Address">Address</vaadin-grid-sorter>
        </template>
        <template>
            [[item.Address]]
        </template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>

    <vaadin-grid-column resizable>
        <template class="header">
            <vaadin-grid-sorter path="ContactNo">Contact No</vaadin-grid-sorter>
        </template>
        <template>
            [[item.ContactNo]]
        </template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>

    <vaadin-grid-column resizable>
        <template class="header">
            <vaadin-grid-sorter path="jobPosition">Job Position</vaadin-grid-sorter>
        </template>
        <template>
            [[item.jobPosition]]
        </template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>
</vaadin-grid>
```

Comment: Have you checked this demo and example https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/html-examples/grid-crud-demos ?

Comment: Oh nice found, I havent check it yet. Thank you @TatuLund